# System enviroment variables in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code

It is possible to access the system environment variables from a plugin in VS? As I can see there no way to obtain them, the only thing I see is that VScode allow to acess the clipboard so I would have to write  program that before it call vscode it copy the environment variables in the clipboard? seem absurd!

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `GetEnvironmentVariable(string variable)` method to retrieve a given parameter into a `string`, e.g:

`string? path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");`

If the variable is not found the returned string is `null`.

Comment: I think my point was not clear, how I do that from plugin code? I'm using typescript and there no Enviroment variable avaible.

Comment: I have no experience of typecript, but I understand the you can access environment variable if your code executes in Node, but not if it executes in the browser.